# Convert string with special characters to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I've the input string coming as `"{"notes_text": "someString"}"`. someString can contain \ or ". And I need to make a JSONObject representing this string.

Simply using the constructor which takes a string as input will throw an exception if it contains special characters.

I've tried a couple of approaches to do this

- use a library to escape the characters - this would result in, for instance, `"{\"notes_text\":\"\"\"}"` or `"{\"notes_text\":\"\\\"}"`. and I would need to change these to `"{\"notes_text\":\"\\\"\"}"` and `"{\"notes_text\":\"\\\\\"}"`  respectively or else it would again throw the exception while converting to JSON Object. Using the replace method in string will convert all the \" in the input string
- don't escape the special chars in the input string and use string replace method to convert \ to \ and " to \". But this would again replace all the double quotes in the input string

I tried using regex but can't get my head around the replacement string in `str.replaceAll("\\\".*\\\".*\\\"", replacemntString)`

Comment: Did you try some JSON frameworks, such as `fastjson`, `gson`? they all could help to deal these problems

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have right now? I have the code below working:         
`Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("message", "Hello \"World\"");
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String payload = om.writeValueAsString(params);
        JsonNode node = om.readTree(payload);
        System.out.println("Result: " + node);`

Comment: @fpezzini 
`new org.json.JSONObject("{\"notes_text\":\"\"\"}")`

Comment: Your JSON string contains 3 quotes in sequence, that does not seem to be a valid JSON string. When you remove the backslashes it becomes {"notes_text":" " "} . You need to remove one of these \" from the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Classes

Here are two classes that solve initial problem with broken json:

```java
public class FixedJson {

    private final String target;

    private final Pattern pattern;

    public FixedJson(String target) {
        this(
            target,
            Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"[^\\w\"]")
        );
    }

    public FixedJson(String target, Pattern pattern) {
        this.target = target;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.pattern.matcher(this.target).replaceAll(
            matchResult -> {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(
                    matchResult.group(),
                    0,
                    matchResult.start(1) - matchResult.start(0)
                );
                sb.append(
                    new Escaped(
                        new Escaped(matchResult.group(1)).value()
                    ).value()
                );
                sb.append(
                    matchResult.group().substring(
                        matchResult.group().length() - (matchResult.end(0) - matchResult.end(1))
                    )
                );
                return sb.toString();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

```java
public class Escaped {

    private final String target;

    private final Pattern pattern;

    public Escaped(String target) {
        this(
            target,
            Pattern.compile("[\\\\\"]")
        );
    }

    public Escaped(String target, Pattern pattern) {
        this.target = target;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.pattern
            .matcher(this.target)
            .replaceAll("\\\\$0");
    }
}
```

## Unit-tests

And I've written unit-tests to prove the correctness:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class FixedJsonTest {

    @Test
    public void normalValue() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"someString\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"someString\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithOneDoubleQuotes() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\"\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\"\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithOneDoubleQuotesAndAnotherValue() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\"\", \"hello\": \"world\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\"\", \"hello\": \"world\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithTwoDoubleQuotes() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\"\\\"\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\"\"\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithTwoDoubleQuotesAndAnotherValue() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\"\\\"\", \"hello\": \"world\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\"\"\", \"hello\": \"world\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithOneSlash() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\\\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithOneSlashAndAnotherValue() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\", \"hello\": \"world\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\\\", \"hello\": \"world\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithTwoSlashes() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\\\\\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\"}").value()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void valueWithTwoSlashesAndAnotherValue() {
        assertEquals(
            "{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\\\\\", \"hello\": \"world\"}",
            new FixedJson("{\"notes_text\": \"\\\\\", \"hello\": \"world\"}").value()
        );
    }
}
```

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class EscapedTest {

    @Test
    public void doubleQuotesTest() {
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("\"").value(),
            "\\\""
        );
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("abc\"def").value(),
            "abc\\\"def"
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void slashesTest() {
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("\\").value(),
            "\\\\"
        );
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("abc\\def").value(),
            "abc\\\\def"
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void mixedTest() {
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("\\\"").value(),
            "\\\\\\\""
        );
        assertEquals(
            new Escaped("abc\\\"def").value(),
            "abc\\\\\\\"def"
        );
    }
}
```

## Full working example

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FixedJsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String invalidJson = "{\"notes_text\":\"\"\"}";

        final String fixedJson = new FixedJson(invalidJson).value();
        System.out.println("fixedJson = " + fixedJson);
    }


    public static class FixedJson {

        private final String target;

        private final Pattern pattern;

        public FixedJson(String target) {
            this(
                target,
                Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"[^\\w\"]")
            );
        }

        public FixedJson(String target, Pattern pattern) {
            this.target = target;
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }

        public String value() {
            return this.pattern.matcher(this.target).replaceAll(
                matchResult -> {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(
                        matchResult.group(),
                        0,
                        matchResult.start(1) - matchResult.start(0)
                    );
                    sb.append(
                        new Escaped(
                            new Escaped(matchResult.group(1)).value()
                        ).value()
                    );
                    sb.append(
                        matchResult.group().substring(
                            matchResult.group().length() - (matchResult.end(0) - matchResult.end(1))
                        )
                    );
                    return sb.toString();
                }
            );
        }
    }

    public static class Escaped {

        private final String target;

        private final Pattern pattern;

        public Escaped(String target) {
            this(
                target,
                Pattern.compile("[\\\\\"]")
            );
        }

        public Escaped(String target, Pattern pattern) {
            this.target = target;
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }

        public String value() {
            return this.pattern
                .matcher(this.target)
                .replaceAll("\\\\$0");
        }
    }
}
```

And its STDOUT:

```
fixedJson = {"notes_text":"\""}
```

This JSON can be validated using following tool: https://jsonlint.com/

## Regex explanation

### `FixedJson` class

The first class `FixedJson` uses regexp for matching JSON lemmas: everything between double quotes (include misplaced double quotes).

For more details see an interactive example here: https://regexr.com/54blf

### `Escaped` class

The second class `Escaped` uses regexp for matching slashes or double quotes. It's required for their escaping.

For more details see an interactive example here: https://regexr.com/54bm1

Comment: woah! great stuff. although, could we leverage the fact that we need to escape these characters only after the **colon** `:`? that way we could avoid the two calls to the `Escaped` class. I'm working on the regex which will work